# Как сделать картинки и многое другое в textView?

Tags: android, textview

Как можно сделать такую же вещь как в [этой статье](https://habrahabr.ru/post/166351/), то есть:
По тэгу ссылку в textView
По тэгу открытие картинки из интернета
Если в тэги с ссылкой присутствует сайт из данного приложения отправить в определенный активити (Это делается, через фильтр в AndroidManifest или самому написать фильтр)
И есть ли готовые примеры или библиотеки по работе с TextView, чтобы можно по тэгу строчка превращалась и выделялась как цитата и тд...

Comment: Чего вам в статье не хватает? Вопрос слишком общий. Разбейте его штук на 7 разных

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Я надеюсь, что мне подскажут, в какую сторону смотреть и что может помочь

Comment: Ну так в статье же, вроде, всё есть.........

Comment: Да тут есть многое, но остались вопросы, если по картинкам, я думаю что можно сделать параллельный поток на скачивание и потом загружать его. Но тогда остается вопрос, где взять название страницы, это "tag" в методе?? И остается вопрос с цитатами и всем остальным, самому прописывать или уже всё написано

Answer (score -1):

Я бы советовал использовать скроллист, и его уже наполнять картинками, тегами, ссылками, всему что душа желает

Чтобы добавить что-то программно в ScrollView надо сначала найти его единственного потомка, а потом уже в него добавлять вьюхи:

```
ScrollView sv = ...;
ViewGroup innerView = sv.getChildAt(0);
//Создаём новую **View**
TextView tv = new TextView(context);
tv.setText("New View");
innerView.addView(tv);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, дайте более развёрнутый ответ. Совет хорошо, пример - лучше.